# Rich text apostrophes aren't printing right

Tags: php, string, encoding, character-encoding

I'm echoing text and all the apostrophes look like this `â` so the word `it's` is printed as `Itâs`. Is there something I need to do to the text, like encode it or decode it or something. How can I fix this?

note: actually, it seems even stackoverflow wouldn't print the characters I see. The apostrophes are changed to the `â` you see above, and 2 boxes next to it which contain the numbers 0080 and 0099. But stackoverflow deletes them from here.

Comment: Where does the text come from? Did you copy the text from Word or another word processor?

Comment: @Cliff, Yes, I think it's a rich-text version of the apostrophe

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I am not a php guy but it might be possible that development IDE would not support UTF-8 or encoding other than ANSI. Workaround is to copy the original text and paste it into the text file which has ANSI encoding. Fix your missing characters manually and then copy the text from that file into your development IDE. If you don't want to do this then you have to enter the actual decimal or hex values of those problem characters.